# Trying to select one record based on a secondary table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, while-loop

I have tried and tried to find an answer to this question, but to no avail.

I am trying to do an update loop based on a table of processors, which works just fine. What I need it to do is select the new "first" record based on who was used last on the previous run of the script.

Here is what I'm stuck on:
 (Dim and set not included for space reasons)

```vb
With Rst
    Rst.MoveFirst

    ' this is the problem code
    RsA.FindFirst (RsA.Fields("Processor") = RsL.Fields("LastPortfolio")) 

    Do While Not Rst.EOF
        If Rst.Fields("Product Type") <> "Acquisition" Then
            Rst.Edit
            Rst.Fields("Allocated Processor").Value = RsA.Fields("Processor")
            Rst.Update
            RsA.MoveNext
            If RsA.EOF Then
                RsA.MoveFirst
            End If
            If RsL.Fields("LastPortfolio").Value <> Rst.Fields("Allocated Processor") Then
                RsL.Edit
                RsL.Fields("LastPortfolio").Value = RsA.Fields("Processor")
                RsL.Update
            End If
        End If
        Rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
DoCmd.Requery
```

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `FindFirst(criteria)` correctly. The `criteria` parameter is a string similar to a `Where` clause in SQL.

I guess you're trying to do this:

```
RsA.FindFirst("[Processor] = '" & RsL.Fields("LastPortfolio").Value & "'")
If Rsa.NoMatch Then

    ' action if not found 

Else

    ' action if found 

End If
```

Comment: This is perfect! thank you so much. the if was not necessary for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The [FindFirst()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194787.aspx) method takes the string parameter. The string parameter must be formatted as a `WHERE` expression, like this:

```
RsA.FindFirst "Processor = ' & "REPLACE(RsL.Fields("LastPortfolio"), "'", "''") & "'"
```

NB: I have used the REPLACE function to get rid off the apostrophes